# How to connect XAMPP MySQL local DB using JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, xampp

I have this Tetris game written in Java, which uses DB to record high scores. It worked ok as long as I was using remote MySQL DB, but now I'm trying to set up localhost DB using XAMPP MySQL and it keeps going like "SQLException: Communications link failure" at command:

```
con = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/score", user, psw);
```

I guess it's either wrong URL or DB configuration, but I really don't know what to check. Any ideas?

EDIT: My friend has fixed my problem by replacing "localhost" in URL by "127.0.0.1" (which was quite embarrassing as you can surely imagine :P ).

So question is: **Why is XAMPP not able to translate "localhost" into IP address and how to fix it?**

Comment: [This post](http://forums.netbeans.org/ntopic4896.html) claims to have fixed it. Check it out.

Comment: Mentioned skip-networking variable is commented in my XAMPP by default, so I afraid this is not the problem..

Comment: Can you browse to the MySQL database with the Query Browser?
I remember running into a similar issue with a Java app that refused to recognize naming in the connection string to MySQL.

Comment: Dont forget this important step on this link - http://ferdidolot.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/java-mysql-jdbc-tutorial-using-netbeans-part-1/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *Why is XAMPP not able to translate "localhost" into IP address and how to fix it?*

This is not a XAMPP problem nor a programming problem. This is more a DNS problem.

To start, do you have a `%SystemRoot%/system32/drivers/etc/hosts` file with the following line as **first** line? (thus, after all comments, but before any other host declarations)

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

**Update:** as per the comments I've [Googled](http://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+jdbc+ipv6) a bit and it look like that the MySQL JDBC driver doesn't eat [IPv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) addresses at all. In other words, you'll need to change `::1` to `127.0.0.1`. But I also found [this topic](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?39,297075,297210) which mentions that you can use the following JVM argument to fix this problem:

```
java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

Comment: What about "::1 localhost"? That should do just the same, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 5):

I tried and got a successful connection. First create a database in **phpmyadmin** - eg. 'mydb'
and then in code put connection.url with this value

```
'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb'
```

If you don't create a database first it wont connect

Answer (score 1):

In MySql you have to allow access for your user from localhost explicitly. Here is an example (taken from [here](http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-create-a-mysql-database-and-set-privileges-to-a-user)):

```
mysql> grant usage on *.* to amarokuser@localhost identified by 'amarokpasswd';
mysql> grant all privileges on amarokdb.* to amarokuser@localhost ;
```

Comment: I'm using root, but I've also tried to create user and give him access and all privileges, just to be sure... not working :/