# Connect Xampp to Netbeans IDE (8.0.2)

Tags: java

You can check the in the image(link at the end of sentence) the library and code as well  ---

[image: 1]

The error is `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`. I already have `mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin` and it's already pasted in my Webserver's lib directory. Below is the code.

```
package databaseinsertexample;

import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class DatabaseInsertExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try
        {
         Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
         Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myteam","root","");
         String sql="insert into teams values(?,?,?)";
         PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement(sql);
         stmt.setString(1,"India");
         stmt.setString(2, "Niraj");
         stmt.setInt(3, 100);
         stmt.execute();
         con.close();
        }  catch(Exception e)
        {
          System.out.println(e);
        }    
    }
    
}
```

On the Localhost site of XAMPP, the Database has been created properly but when I'm executing the program on my Java file via Netbeans it's not reflecting on the Database. Please help I'm new to this Programming world, I checked on YouTube still I'm not able to clear this doubt of mine.

Answer (score 0):

change your clase forName like this.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

And also please refer this question - [How to connect XAMPP MySQL local DB using JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168969/how-to-connect-xampp-mysql-local-db-using-jdbc)

Comment: Thank you for helping out @Yasas Naveen. Code executed properly, and thanks for the link too!

Comment: You are welcome @NirajVora. if your problem solved please accept the answer.